# how to join two tables using wildcards giving only best match per row from table1

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, wildcard

How can I limit the results of a query that uses a wildcard join between two tables to only one result (best match) per row from table 1?

I've got the following data structures:

```
table t1:
ID   AccountStr
1    7
2    71
3    72
4    721
5    73
6    8

table t2:
ID   AccountPattern   AccountType
1    7                Type01
2    72               Type02xxx
```

desired query result:

```
Line AccountStr       AccountType
1    7                Type01
2    71               Type01
3    72               Type02xxx
4    721              Type02xxx
5    73               Type01
6    8                NULL
```

code I used (Syntax: MS Access SQL):

```
SELECT T1.AccountStr, T2.AccountType
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.AccountStr Like T2.AccountPattern+"*"
ORDER BY T1.AccountStr, T2.AccountType;
```

result of my query, unwanted lines marked:

```
Line AccountStr       AccountType
1    7                Type01
2    71               Type01
3    72               Type01     **unwanted line** 
4    72               Type02xxx
5    72               Type01     **unwanted line**
6    721              Type02xxx
7    73               Type01
8    8                NULL
```

I understand, why my query gives all matches - `72` matches pattern `7*` - but since there is a better matching pattern `72*` I need to only get that one in my results.

I thought about a descending sort order of `t2` - AccountPattern `72` before `7` - and limiting pattern match results to first row only, but I don't know how to do that - or maybe ther's a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery with `TOP 1`:

```
SELECT T1.AccountStr,
       (SELECT TOP 1 T2.AccountType
        FROM T2 
        WHERE T1.AccountStr Like T2.AccountPattern + "*"
        ORDER BY LEN(T2.AccountPattern) DESC, T2.AccountPattern
       ) as AccountType
FROM T1 
ORDER BY T1.AccountStr;
```

This returns the longest matching pattern.

Comment: needed to omit the trailing `T2.AccountType` after `ODER BY` - MS Access can't handle this. Maybe you want to edit your code @Gordon Linoff